# columns average C

Tags: c, 2d, average

I have the next function in which i want to find the average of the N columns, but after finishing the  M lines i take wrong inputs in the averages_days array, any idea?

```
int day_max_average(int a[M][N]) {
    int max = 0, day, i, j, averages_days[N], sum = 0,k=0;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            sum += a[j][i];
            if(j==N-1){
                averages_days[k] = sum / N;
                k++;
            }
        }
        sum = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", averages_days[i]);
        if (averages_days[i] >= max) {
            max = averages_days[i];
            day = i + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("H %d (%d.2) \n", day, max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should reset `sum` after assigning to `averages_days[k]`?

Comment: You can replace `k` with `i`, in the first `for` loop. That makes the logic clearer. Also, in the second `for` loop, replace `N` with `M`. Also, before entering the second `for` loop, initialize `max` with `averages_days[0]`, because the maximum value might be less than `0`.

Comment: Can you provide some expected results and what you get?

Comment: this question is about a runtime error.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: it's ok now
  int day_max_average(int a[M][N]) {
 int max = 0, day, i, j, averages_days[N], sum = 0,k=0;

 for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
   sum += a[i][j];
  } 
  
  averages_days[k] = sum / M;
  sum = 0;
  k++;
 }

 for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  printf("%d\n", averages_days[i]);
  if (averages_days[i] >= max) {
   max = averages_days[i];
   day = i + 1;
  }
 }

 printf(" %d  (%d.2) \n", day, max);

 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

it's ok now,
  int day_max_average(int a[M][N]) {
    int max = 0, day, i, j, averages_days[N], sum = 0,k=0;

```
for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        sum += a[i][j];
    } 

    averages_days[k] = sum / M;
    sum = 0;
    k++;
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", averages_days[i]);
    if (averages_days[i] >= max) {
        max = averages_days[i];
        day = i + 1;
    }
}

printf(" %d  (%d.2) \n", day, max);

return 0;
```

}